# Kafka, change broker ip without changing broker id

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 8 node kafka cluster (broker.id range 1 to 8) on AWS ec2 instances distributed among 2 AZs (1a and 1b). In order to have multi AZ cluster, I need to migrate 4 brokers into remaining two AZs (1c and 1d).

If I create a new ec2 instance in 1c, I will definitely get a new ip address.
My question here is, Can I use same broker.id for the new node after removing older node which had same broker.id

Example :
broker.id = 1, IP = 1.1.1.1, AZ = 1a

Now, I want to move this node to 1c, so I stop broker service on (1.1.1.1) and spin up a new node in 1c with an empty disk

broker.id = 1, IP = 2.2.2.2, AZ = 1c

Now, I will just start the broker service on new node. Will this create any issues in kafka cluster, since we are changing the node without changing the broker.id?

Answer (score 0):

There is a generated `meta.properties` file on the broker that holds a clusterId, which might cause you to run into issues.

Otherwise, the old broker information is still maintained in Zookeeper for partition replicas, and without also moving the topic data, then replication will need to happen after the new broker starts correctly (e.g. the inter-broker listeners are configured to communicate across regions)

The *safer* approach would be to use `kafka-reassign-partitions` tool to move partitions off the brokers you want to migrate to a broker with another ID, then shutdown and install new servers *with a new ID*, then run the tool again to move the partitions back to those new IDs.

Comment: I am using kafka version kafka_2.12-2.3.1 and in meta.properties file I don't see clusterId. Sample content from meta.properties file 
#
#Thu Dec 23 09:35:04 UTC 2021
version=0
broker.id=1
Maybe its been added in later versions.

Comment: Yeah, I want to say around version 2.8